# Is the expression "Do without" commonly used?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, expressions

I would like to say that a someone cannot leave something because he/she benefits from this something a lot. He/She mainly depends on them. What is the best word that describes it? Should I say "discontinue" or "do without" or something else?

For example:

> Humanity cannot do without technology.
>
> A father cannot do without his son. He really loves him.
>
> I can not do without my necklace. It's a gift from my best friend.

Is the expression "Do without" okay in those examples? Or should I use another idiom or word?

Comment: *Do without*, as you have used it, is entirely idiomatic.

Comment: It boils down to personal taste, but I would only use "do without" in the first case because I interpret that idiom to mean "to function without". So, I would only use that for functional objects, like technology. Tying it to love or emotion seems odd. Example 1: I cannot do without my necklace: it goes perfectly with my dress. Example 2: A father cannot do without his son in this society because only a son can inherit farming land.

Comment: @urnonav - I think you've nailed it. Going back to the OP's original sentence about the necklace, I think we could change the "do without" to something like: _"I can't bear to give away my necklace; it's a gift from my best friend."_

Comment: Yes, it is very commonly used.

Comment: In some situations (such as the necklace sentence) "go without" might work better. It depends on context, as others have noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that do without in all of those cases sounds the best. Discontinue sounds a bit too formal and can be seen as speaking a bit robotic, especially when taking about a father and his son.

Answer (score 0):

"Do without" is commonly used.
The meaning is more literal than how the original poster wishes to use it.

Of the original poster's three examples:

- The first one is a correct usage of "do without".  It implies that a large fraction of humanity would die without technology.
- A particular father might not be able to do without his son, because he loves him so much.  It implies that he would become seriously depressed or commit suicide.
- The third example's reason does not match the usage of "do without".  If the context were about going to a particular event where the necklace would be the difference between having a good time and having a miserable time, then "do without" would be appropriate.